# NotesException:Older version on server does not support this method

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotusscript, ls2j

Lotusscript calling Java class get this error.
abstract:
Product Area: Domino Designer on Eclipse (DDE)

Technical Area: Application Development

Platform: Windows 2008 R2 64bit

Release: 8.5.3

Reproducible: Always

1 create SqlTest script libray(Java) in Notes database.
Model.java：

```
    import java.sql.Connection;

    import java.sql.DriverManager;

    import java.sql.SQLException;

    import java.sql.Statement;

    import lotus.domino.*;

    public class Model{

    /**

    Get database connection
    @return
    */

    public static Connection getConn(){

    Connection conn = null;

    String SqlDriverName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";

    String SqlDBUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://22.11.95.30:1433;DatabaseName=TMSTEST";

    String SqlUserName = "sa";

    String Sqlpwd = "1q2w3e4r!";

    try {

    Class.forName(SqlDriverName);

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(SqlDBUrl, SqlUserName, Sqlpwd);

    System.out.println("database connection sucess");

    } catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

    System.out.println("database connection failure");

    }

    return conn;

    }

    public static boolean test1(String id){

    //System.out.println("---------------------");

    Connection conn = getConn();

    Statement stmt = null;

    String sql;

    // Open the current Notes db

    try {

    Session s = NotesFactory.createSession("22.11.95.100:63148", "admin test/testeam", "testtest");

    System.out.println("session is OK");

    Database db = s.getCurrentDatabase();

    //  System.out.println("Title of URL database: \"" + db.getTitle() + "\"");

    if (db.isOpen())

    System.out.println("Is open");

    else

    System.out.println("Not open");
    Document doc = null;

    //through the id para get the Notesdocument

    doc = db.getDocumentByUNID(id);

    System.out.println(id);

    //insert the Notesdocument data to sql

    if (doc != null) {

    sql = "insert into TEST_USER(userID, userName,xqbh) values('123456','"+doc.getItemValueString("fld_xqbh")+"', '"+doc.getItemValueString("fld_xqmc")+"')";

    System.out.println("SQL :"+sql);

    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    stmt.execute(sql);

    System.out.println("excute finish");

    return true;

    }else{

    return false;

    }

    } catch (NotesException e) {

    // TODO auto generate catch block

    e.printStackTrace();

    return false;

    }catch(SQLException se){

    se.printStackTrace();

    return false;

    }finally{

    try{

    if(stmt != null) stmt.close();

    if(conn != null) conn.close();

    }catch(Exception e1){

    e1.printStackTrace();

    }

    }

    }

    }
```

2 in the Notes form:

```
    Uselsx "*javacon"
    Use "SqlTest"


    Function jTest(id As String) As Boolean

        Dim jSession As New JAVASESSION

        Dim jClass As JAVACLASS

        Dim jObj As JavaObject

        Set jClass = jSession.GetClass("Model")

        'Msgbox jClass.className 

        Call jClass.test1(id)
    End Function
```

3 use the java class through Lotusscript:

```
'call java class

Call jTest(doc.UniversalID)
```

4 debug the program find the error in java console log through IDE(Lotus Domino Designer).use some print sentences and find the error line(Java):

```
   Database db = s.getCurrentDatabase();
```

5 I have had seen follow posts.

[Invoking method on a Java class from lotus script (LS2J)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912808/invoking-method-on-a-java-class-from-lotus-script-ls2j)

[passing LotusScript parameter to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725023/passing-lotusscript-parameter-to-java)

google Nothing,trouble for days.
thanks everyone,thanks in advance.First Posts in stackoverflow.

Comment: So just to clarify you get that "server does not support this method" when calling s.getCurrentDatabase(), right?  And do you test the Session object for validity before using it?

Comment: in the Domino Server test program show :NotesException:Older version on server does not support this method. and console print Session is OK.in a Notes Client machine:Test it receive follow:NotesException: Could not get IOR from Domino Server :http://22.11.141.77:63148/diiop_ior.txt.Such a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you get your session: you open a complete new one that has nothing to do with the currently open session. That new session does not have a current database as it is not connected to you frontend session.

Just initialize your session with this line:

```
Session session = getSession();
```

Then getCurrentDatabase will work.

Comment: thanks for reply.the Model.java not extend AgentBase,so this is Not work.I check the Designer Help doc

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Torsten Link.
I test the java script library many times,all failure. New a Javaagent not java script library then everything is clear.

core LotusScript code:

```
    Dim agent As NotesAgent
    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
    Set agent = db.GetAgent("javaAgent")
    If agent.RunOnServer(doc.NotesID) = 0 Then
      Messagebox "Agent ran",, "Success"
    Else
      Messagebox "Agent did not run",, "Failure"
    End If
```

core javaagent code:

```
     Agent agent = agentContext.getCUrrentAgent()
     Document doc = db.getDocumentbyID(agent.getParameterDocID())
```

Notice:Runtime security level,You need to allow restricted operations.